# How to create dynamic gridview with delete and add functionality in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to create a gridview in which i add and delete row at runtime in C#asp.net

Comment: Is the postback to the server happening each time for every row you add or delete? Or you want a solution such that you complete the postback only once after you are done with all changes?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ASP/.NEt tuterials, http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials

Comment: that's a good link.  I'm just going to post the direct link that answers his specific question from the link you posted above http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/an-overview-of-inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-cs